Revert complete git repo state to point in past
I'm debugging CI pipeline, where scripts are referencing branch names. I can only see this bug appear in particular run in the past. So I need bring repo to that state to see what happened.
I know how to revert local state to commit in the past
But how do I make every branch point to where it was in the past, to reproduce exact state repo was in?

"…how do I make every branch point to where it was in the past…?" Try git reflog <branch> for every branch but please be warned that reflogs are only stored for limited time. If you can find old commits for every branch just do git branch --force <branch> <commit>. Don't forget to make a backup for your repo before resetting many branches.

two (different) suggestions: 1. you can create a separate remote repository (e.g: github.com/myself/myproject-debug) to which you force push the past state of your branches -- see phd's comment above, or scan the history of your repo at the time your piepeline failed -- and let the CICD pipeline kick in on that repo. 2. if the CICD scritpts are part of your rpeo, create a new branch (e.g: git checkout -b cicd/debug) and edit the CICD scripts to forcefully set the state you want (e.g: git branch -f <branchname> <thatcommit> for a number of braches) before they run.

wouldn't it be possible to run the pipeline using the commits involved instead of the branches (having them pointing to those commits) involved?
